# Everything stopped working when i copied my simple code from one project to another, what happend?

Tags: c++

i have no clue what happened but nothing works.

I'm relatively new to c++ so maybe that's it, i know other programming languages

this is just a bunch of bad code i wrote, its the entire program, and when i copied it from another project everything stopped working, nothings printing.

it might be a pain to understand this but it was a 2d game (kinda)

-both projects had no special settings turned on

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <Windows.h>

int screenWidth = 240;      // console screen width
int screenHeight = 63;      // console screen height
int mapWidth = 16;      // map textfile width
int mapHeight = 16;     // map textfile height

float playerX = 5.0f;       // start pos x
float playerY = 4.0f;       // start pos y
float playerSpeed = 2.0f;

bool facingRight = true;

std::wstring map;
int main()
{
    wchar_t* screen = new wchar_t[screenWidth * screenHeight];
    HANDLE hConsole = CreateConsoleScreenBuffer(GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CONSOLE_TEXTMODE_BUFFER, NULL);
    DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0;
    map += L"################";
    map += L"#..............#";
    map += L"#.............##";
    map += L"###..####...#..#";
    map += L"#.......#...#..#";
    map += L"#.......#...##.#";
    map += L"#.......#...#..#";
    map += L"#######.#...#.##";
    map += L"#...........#..#";
    map += L"#...######..##.#";
    map += L"#...#....#..#..#";
    map += L"#...#....#..#.##";
    map += L"#...##DD###.#..#";
    map += L"#....##...####.#";
    map += L"#.....#........#";
    map += L"################";
    
    auto frameTime1 = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto frameTime2 = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    while (true)
    {
        frameTime2 = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        std::chrono::duration<float> frameTime = frameTime2 - frameTime1;
        frameTime1 = frameTime2;
        float deltatime = frameTime.count();

        // Handle CCW Rotation
        if (GetAsyncKeyState((unsigned short)'A') & 0x8000 || (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LEFT) & 0x8000))
        {
            playerX -= playerSpeed * deltatime;
            if (map.c_str()[(int)playerY * mapWidth + (int)playerX] == '#')
            {
                playerX += playerSpeed * deltatime;
            }
        }

        // Handle CW Rotation
        if (GetAsyncKeyState((unsigned short)'D') & 0x8000 || (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RIGHT) & 0x8000))
        {
            playerX += playerSpeed * deltatime;
            if (map.c_str()[(int)playerY * mapWidth + (int)playerX] == '#')
            {
                playerX -= playerSpeed * deltatime;
            }
        }

        // Handle Forwards movement & collision
        if (GetAsyncKeyState((unsigned short)'W') & 0x8000 || (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP) & 0x8000))
        {
            playerY -= playerSpeed * deltatime;
            if (map.c_str()[(int)playerY * mapWidth + (int)playerX] == '#')
            {
                playerY += playerSpeed * deltatime;
            }
        }

        // Handle backwards movement & collision
        if ((GetAsyncKeyState((unsigned short)'S') & 0x8000) || (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DOWN) & 0x8000))
        {
            playerY += playerSpeed * deltatime;
            if (map.c_str()[(int)playerY * mapWidth + (int)playerX] == '#')
            {
                playerY -= playerSpeed * deltatime;
            }
        }
        
        for (int x = 0; x < screenWidth; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < screenHeight; y++)
            {
                
                if(map.c_str()[int(playerY - 2.6665 + y / (9 * 1.5)) * mapWidth + int(playerX - 5 + x / (16 * 1.5))] == '#')
                {
                    screen[y * screenWidth + x] = 'i';
                }
                else if (map.c_str()[int(playerY - 2.6665 + y / (9 * 1.5)) * mapWidth + int(playerX - 5 + x / (16 * 1.5))] == 'D')
                {
                    screen[y * screenWidth + x] = '=';
                }
                else {
                    screen[y * screenWidth + x] = ' ';
                }
                
            }
        }

        swprintf_s(screen, 80, L"X=%3.2f, Y=%3.2f FPS=%3.2f ", playerX, playerY, 1.0f / deltatime);
        for (int mapx = 0; mapx < mapWidth; mapx++)
        {
            for (int mapy = 0; mapy < mapWidth; mapy++)
            {
                screen[(mapy + 1) * screenWidth + mapx] = map[mapy * mapWidth + mapx];
            }
        }
        for (int i = -3; i < 6; i++)
        {
            for (int l = -2; l < 3; l++)
            {
                if (i < -1)
                {
                    screen[(screenHeight / 2 + i) * screenWidth + screenWidth / 2 + l] = '#';
                }
                else {
                    screen[(screenHeight / 2 + i) * screenWidth + screenWidth / 2 + l] = 0x2592;
                }
                
            }
        }
        screen[((int)playerY+1) * screenWidth + (int)playerX] = 'O';
        screen[screenWidth * screenHeight] = '\0';
        WriteConsoleOutputCharacter(hConsole, screen, screenWidth * screenHeight, { 0,0 }, &dwBytesWritten);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You never call [`SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsoleactivescreenbuffer) to make `hConsole` the active buffer so it isn't displayed.

Comment: Thank you! So it was a simple mistake. as always